# What am I doing wrong with this epsilon delta exercise?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, inequality, epsilon-delta

I'm having trouble with this exercise, apparently I'm wrong, however there's no process explained in the answers. The answer should be $\delta = 2\epsilon$

Prove the limit $\lim_{x \to 9} \sqrt{x - 5} = 2$

$L = 2,\ c = 9,\ f(x) = \sqrt{x - 5}$

We will work with the following inequalities

$\epsilon \lt 0$

$0 \lt |x - c | \lt \delta$

$|f(x) - L| \lt \epsilon$

$0 \lt |x - 9| \lt \delta$

$|\sqrt{x - 5} - 2| \lt \epsilon$

First we find the open inverval in which $x$ has to be.

$|\sqrt{x - 5} - 2| \lt \epsilon$

$- \epsilon \lt \sqrt{x - 5} - 2 \lt \epsilon$

$2 - \epsilon \lt \sqrt{x - 5} \lt \epsilon + 2$

$\epsilon^2 - 4\epsilon + 4\lt x - 5 \lt \epsilon^2 + 4 \epsilon + 4,\ x \neq 5$

$\epsilon^2 - 4\epsilon + 9 \lt x \lt \epsilon^2 + 4 \epsilon + 9,\ x \neq 5$

Since we will probably never reach 5, we don't care about it. We'll end with the interval $(\epsilon^2 - 4\epsilon + 9,\ \epsilon^2 + 4 \epsilon + 9)$

$\delta = \min{\{ 9 - (\epsilon^2 - 4\epsilon + 9),\ (\epsilon^2 + 4 \epsilon + 9) - 9\}} = \min{\{ \epsilon^2 - 4\epsilon,\ \epsilon^2 + 4 \epsilon\}}$

Comment: It should be $4\epsilon -\epsilon^{2}$ instead of $\epsilon^{2}-4\epsilon$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why/Where $(-\epsilon)^2 = \epsilon^2$

Comment: The last equality you have written is wrong.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I changed it, still the answer isn't correct

Comment: Minimum of $4\epsilon -\epsilon^{2}$ and $4\epsilon +\epsilon^{2}$  is $4\epsilon -\epsilon^{2}$ . Is that the given answer? In any case **$\delta$ is not unique** and you don't have to come with the same answer as the one given.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I just figured out that the website with the answers was incorrect, I found some other source which got the same answer as me, sorry for wasting your time